# how to retrieve original matrix from RGB image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

In Matlab, how to retrieve the original matrix from a RGB image? For my case, I have a 50x360 matrix. After imagesc, I save it as jpeg file. And now, I need to load back the matrix(50x360) from the jpeg file. Is there anyway to do it? If use imread, the matrix dimension will be 1366x628x3 which is different with 50x360. Thanks.

Comment: Post your code for `imread`, it should work

Comment: In addition to your code, please post the (expected) image dimensions and the dimensions of the resulting matrix.

Comment: my original matrix dimension is 50x360. But the matrix dimension retrieved from image by using imread is 628x1366x3.

Comment: if you inspect the image outside of matlab, what is its resolution?

Comment: The dimension is 1366x628 pixels and resolution is 96 dpi.

Comment: In that case the dimensions of the matrix from imread is consistent: both the image and the matrix are 1366 horizontal by 628 vertical. The extra '3' dimension after imread results from there being 3 color planes; R, G and B. I'm not sure what you mean by "my original matrix dimension is 50x360". Is this perhaps the matrix used to generate the image?

Comment: Yes,is the matrix used to generate the image by using imagesc.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
im = imread('image.jpg')
size(im)
ycoord = 20;
xcoord = 20;
im(ycoord,xcoord,1) %for R
im(ycoord,xcoord,2) %for G
im(ycoord,xcoord,2) %for B
```

Comment: But I get ??? Undefined function or variable 'ycoord' when executes im(ycoord,xcoord,1).

Comment: you have to say what xcoord and ycoord you want, use integers: im(20,20,3) for example.

Comment: I see.But my case is like this, I used imagesc for a 50x360 matrix. And now I want to retrieve back the 50x360 matrix, but when I used imread,it give me a 628x1366x3 matrix.Anyway to get back the 50x360 matrix? Thanks.

Comment: @Thy: I think you need to update your question to clearly reflect what you're doing. What the problem is, what you tried and what your getting.